# unexpected behavior in asin()

Tags: r

I'm running into odd behaviour with the `asin()` function in R. I have an expression that occasionally evaluates to -1 that I pass to `asin()`. Sometimes `asin()` responds with the expected value `asin(-1) = 1.57....` other times it responds with `NaNs produced`.

The code below gives an example (from a larger function that computes growing degree days for insects):

```
 # works
 tempMax <- 22.6
 tempMin <- 10.0
 threshold <- 10

 meanT     <- (tempMax + tempMin) / 2

 amplitude <- (tempMax - tempMin) /2

 thetaSub <- ( (threshold - meanT)/amplitude )

 thetaOut  <- asin( thetaSub)

 # fails
tempMax <- 22.7
tempMin <- 10.0
threshold <- 10

meanT     <- (tempMax + tempMin) / 2

amplitude <- (tempMax - tempMin) /2

thetaSub <- ( (threshold - meanT)/amplitude )

thetaOut  <- asin( thetaSub)
```

Note that in both examples `thetaSub` evaluates to -1, but `asin` only 'works' in the first example.

Testing the function it seems that I get NaNs when `tempMin == threshold` and the integer value of `tempMax` is even and the decimal portion is .7 (e.g., 22.7, 24.7, 26.7).

I suspect that's not the reason, but just other cases that elict the same error. I'm guessing it's something to do with how the value of `thetaSub` is interpreted by `asin`, but I can't figure out why it works sometimes and not others.

edit.

@James has identified my problem as a floating point issue. How do I force the asin to 'ignore' the decimal places?

Comment: The second `thetaSub` is actually below `-1`.

Comment: re: your edit, I expanded my answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a floating point issue. The way floating point numbers work is that all numbers need to be mapped to the nearest one which can be expressed as a finite sum of powers of two and this may lead to small inaccuracies in the expected output and can be dependent upon how the numbers are calculated.

```
print(thetaSub,digits=22)
[1] -1.000000000000000222045
```

You should modify your code to use `asin(max(-1,min(1,thetaSub)))` to protect against this issue. If you are doing calculations in a vectorised way use `pmax` and `pmin` instead.